# Delete entry with time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to delete entry in my table on every 3 seconds. Once I entered all the data, system should be able to delete the every entries which are occurring 3 seconds after first entry. I tried this code, but it didn't work out well.

```
delete from table_8
where datediff(second,Date_Time,Getdate()) < 3
```

Comment: mssql, I presume?

Comment: which sql driver are you using? mssql, mysql, postgre?   If you're using mysql, then you need to specify and INTERVAL clause which determines what scale 3 is on, its really vague here, is it 3 minutes, seconds, hours, days, years...or what?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2014 Management studio

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that some values might be negative.  I think this is clearer:

```
delete
    from table_8
    where date_time < dateadd(second, -3, getdate());
```

This can also take advantage of an index on `table_8(date_time)` for performance.